# Is there a CMS that can make it easy for a non technical person to take care of an Android application's back-end?

Tags: android, content-management-system, backend, developer-tools

I'm building an application for an small team and i believe that people will not  be able to spend a lot of time to update the data of the application , therefore I'm looking for a CMS  (like WordPress or Joomla )which can make things easier to maintain . Is there anything  that can be of use for me  as a developer and the maintenance guy?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [Parse](https://parse.com/products/android)? It is perfect for small applications. You're going to have to pay for it though if your application grows.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it and give you a feedback how useful it is. Are there any other that I should have a look at ?